# How do I tell how popular a theme is?

Tags: themes

Guessing the answer is no, but just wondering if there's a way to tell how popular a theme is.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are talking about commercial/premium themes the obvious answer is Google WordPress (theme name) and compare the results. A popular theme would likely have more results.

WordPress.org [lists the theme's it contains](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/browse/popular/) according to how many times they have been downloaded.

Comment: +1 @M.Taylor: A Google search would count by pages, not sites; though it's hard to tell what a "site" might be, it is easy to see that page counts and "site" counts would be order of magnitudes different. The WordPress "Most Popular" page appears to sort by "Last Week" not "All Time" - though gathering the all time data would just be a matter of scraping it from the 1,385 theme stat pages on WordPress. Thanks, your answer is fine as is, though going to wait to see if a better one pops-up.

Comment: I would be interested to see if there is a better solution too. In the end its all speculative as the most theme producers will not share exactly how many of each theme they have sold.

Comment: +1 @M.Taylor: Well, if you're interested to see if there is a better solution too... :-) ...upvote the question. Also, agree, it's unlikely that there's an incentive on anyone's part to make it easy to know the answer to the question. Cheers!